# propositional logic homework problems

Tags: logic

Having some trouble with a couple of problems in my metalogic homework. We are using an axiomatic system with the following axioms:

> $\vdash B\rightarrow(A\rightarrow B)$
>
> $\vdash (\neg A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow((\neg A\rightarrow \neg
> B)\rightarrow A$
>
> $\vdash (A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow
> B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$

We are also allowed to use Modus Ponens in our derivations.

I'm having trouble showing the following (note that the only symbols part of our language are parentheses, negations, arrows, and letters):

1. $\{x, \neg y\}\vdash \neg(x\rightarrow y)$
2. $\vdash x\leftrightarrow x$ which is the same as $\vdash \neg((x\rightarrow x)\rightarrow \neg(x\rightarrow x))$
3. $\{x, y\} \vdash x\wedge y $ which is the same as $\{x, y\} \vdash \neg(x\rightarrow \neg y)$

I also proved many of the excercises, whose answers I can use in all my derivations:

[image]

I'm still not completely comfortable with the deduction theorem and I'm sure that I could possibly abuse it to solve (2) and (3). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

We assume as only *connective* the *conditional* ($\rightarrow$).

We assume also the *propositional constant* $\bot$ (*falsum* or *absurdity*; we can think to it also as a $0$-place connective), and we define the *negation* of $p$ in this way : $\lnot p$ is $p \rightarrow \bot$.

The other connectives are defined as usual : $p \land q$ is $\lnot (p \rightarrow \lnot q)$, $p \lor q$ is $\lnot p \rightarrow q$ and $p \leftrightarrow q$ is $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p)$.

***1)*** We will use the *Deduction Theorem*, i.e.

> if $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$, then $\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B$.

We have that :

$\{ x, x \rightarrow y \} \vdash y$ --- by *modus ponens*

So that :

$\vdash x \rightarrow ((x \rightarrow y ) \rightarrow y)$ --- by *DT* twice.

Now we will use *Transitivity*, an we apply it to:

$\vdash x \rightarrow [(x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow y]$  --- it is $A \rightarrow B$

$\vdash [(x \rightarrow y) \rightarrow y] \rightarrow [\lnot y \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow y)]$ --- by Lemma 2.3(b), with *DT* --- it is $B \rightarrow C$

So we have :

$\vdash x \rightarrow [\lnot y \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow y)]$ --- it is $A \rightarrow C$.

Now we apply *modus ponens* twice :

> $\{ x, \lnot y \} \vdash \lnot (x \rightarrow y)$.

***3)*** Using the definition of $x \land y$ as $\lnot(x \rightarrow \lnot y)$, from *1)* , with $\lnot y$ in place of $y$ and using *Double Negation*, we have :

> $\{ x, y \} \vdash \lnot (x \rightarrow \lnot y)$.

***2)*** Using the definition of

$x \leftrightarrow x$ as $(x \rightarrow x) \land (x \rightarrow x)$,

and using the definition of

$x \land y$ as $\lnot(x \rightarrow \lnot y)$

we have that :

$x \leftrightarrow x$ is $\lnot [(x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow x)]$.

Now the derivation :

using *Axiom 2*, (1a) and *Transitivity*, we have :

$\vdash (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow \lnot B) \rightarrow \lnot A)$

putting $A$ in place of $B$ we have :

$\vdash (A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow \lnot A)$.

Using Example 2 (i.e.$\vdash A \rightarrow A$) we finally have, by *modus ponens* :

$\vdash ((A \rightarrow \lnot A) \rightarrow \lnot A)$.

This in turn gives us :

$\vdash [(x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow x)] \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow x)$

Using Lemma 2.3(b) we have :

$\vdash \lnot \lnot (x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot [(x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow x)]$

Using 1(a) and *Transitivity*, we have :

$\vdash (x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot [(x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow x)]$

Now apply *modus ponens* using Example 2 (i.e. $\vdash x \rightarrow x$) to get :

> $\vdash \lnot [(x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \lnot (x \rightarrow x)]$ that is $x \leftrightarrow x$.

Comment: Thank you tremendously for this answer! My main problem is that I get "stuck" in deductions and forget to think "outside" the language. Our exam is open book and open notes so I'm trying to prove as much as I can before hand (to make life easier during) -- do yo you have any suggestions of theorems I should attempt to prove in preparation?

Comment: I've no "special" set of exercises to suggest you: try with the ones in your textbook. Otherwise, check with truth-tables for some tautologies, and then try to prove them (due to the Completeness Th for *propositional logic*, every tautology must be provable).